# mysql stored procedure error: missing semicolon

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have following store procedure. It is give me some error

```
DROP procedure IF exists getQueueMessage;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getQueueMessage`(msg varchar(100))
BEGIN

SELECT `Name` FROM queues WHERE Id  IN (
SELECT PhysicalQueueId FROM indexqueuemaps WHERE ConditionFieldValue = msg)
END
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is giving me `missing semicolon error`. Don't know Why this error is getting. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try like this:

```
DROP procedure IF exists getQueueMessage;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getQueueMessage`(msg varchar(100))
BEGIN

SELECT `Name` FROM queues WHERE Id  IN (
SELECT PhysicalQueueId FROM indexqueuemaps WHERE ConditionFieldValue = msg);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4):

There's only one `BEGIN` and two `END`s, remove the 2nd `END` and you should be fine.

Comment: I didn't get what's the difference between accepted answer and the question. You gave perfect explanation.

Answer (score -3):

Replace `root`@`localhost` with root@`localhost`